# collection view with buttons

Tags: ios, button, uicollectionview

I have a collection view of labels and now need one with buttons, but it is not quite the same setting it up. I currently call the label collection view like this

```
 [(UILabel *)self.EventTitles[i] setText:[object objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

which works fine but set text is not an option for UIButton collection views so I need a slight alteration in which I can not figure out. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in the case of the UIButtons you want to change their title. To do that you need to use the following method:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```

In your specific case of a UIButton collection you can do the following:

```
[(UIButton *)self.buttonCollection[i] setTitle:@"yourTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```